# React Hooks selecting data to a date picker

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a MUI date picker in my React app that I want to use with serverside data.
I'm returning the correct data in my console log that I pass in my useState hook `const [availableDate, setAvailableDate] = useState({});` and now want to pass the selected date into the picker:

**returned JSON**

```
  const data = [
    {
      date: '05/05/21',
      timeSlots: [
        {
          end: '11:00',
          start: '12:00'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      date: '05/05/24',
      timeSlots: [
        {
          end: '13:00',
          start: '14:00'
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

**Date Picker**

```
const [availableDate, setAvailableDate] = useState({});
const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState(availableDate);

//set current date as default

var curr = new Date();
function setDate(dat) {
    let datt = {
      date: {// ... returend date},
      start: '11:40',
      end: '13:00',
    };
    service.stepDate.setCvData(datt);
  }
  curr.setDate(curr.getDate());
  var date = curr.toISOString().substr(0, 10);
```

**Date Picker**
I tried mapping the array data in my date picker but this just returns multiple pickers.

```
      {availableDates.map((index) => (
        <div className="calendarWrapper">
          <form noValidate>
            <TextField
              key={index.id}
              minDate={today}
              id="date"
              type="date"
              onChange={setDate}
              defaultValue={date}
            />
          </form>
        </div>
      ))}
```

How do I extract the selected date `ex:  date: "2021/05/24"` from the json and pass it into my `setDate()` function?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, onChange interface is the following

```
  onChange(e) { 
    // e.target.value
  }
```

so you won't be able to get your date from e directly.

Also date is an object, which can't be `{}` initially, `null` could be one option, or `new Date()`.